# библиотека fullpage js

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage

Скачал и подключил библиотеку fullpage.js, в консоль пишет

```
fullpage.js:3596 fullPage: Fullpage.js version 3 has changed its license to GPLv3 and it requires a `licenseKey` option. Read about it here:
fullpage.js:3596 fullPage: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#options.
```

Я так понимаю что сейчас библиотека работает только с ключом? Если да, то кроме записи в консоли она не вредит? Можно ли где скачать старую версию без ключа

Answer (score 0):

Старые версии доступны в репозитории проекта - https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/releases, по лицензии и ключу надо понимать коммерческое использование проекта у вас или open source, подробности есть в документации проекта.